# BIU numbers (or Sumdivized numbers)

Tags: code-golf, sequence

## How to spot them

Take a positive integer k. Find its **divisors**. Find the **distinct prime factors of each divisor**. Sum all these factors together. If this number (sum) is a divisor of k (**if the sum divides k**) then, this number k, is a **BIU number**

## Examples

Let's take the number `54`
Find all the **divisors:** `[1, 2, 3, 6, 9, 18, 27, 54]`
Find the **distinct prime factors** of each divisor
**NOTE:** For the case of `1` we take as distinct prime factor `1`

```
1  -> 1  
2  -> 2  
3  -> 3  
6  -> 2,3  
9  -> 3  
18 -> 2,3  
27 -> 3  
54 -> 2,3
```

Now we take the sum of **all** these prime factors
`1+2+3+2+3+3+2+3+3+2+3=27`
`27` divides 54 (leaves no remainder)
So, `54` **is** a **BIU number**.

Another (quick) example for `k=55`
**Divisors:** `[1,5,11,55]`
**Sum of distinct prime factors:** `1+5+11+5+11=33`
`33` is **NOT** a divisor of 55, that's why `55` is **NOT** a **BIU number**.

## BIU numbers

Here are the first 20 of them:

> 1,21,54,290,735,1428,1485,1652,2262,2376,2580,2838,2862,3003,3875,4221,4745, 5525,6750,7050...

but this list goes on and there are many **BIU numbers** that are waiting to be descovered by you!

## The Challenge

Given an integer `n>0` as **input**, **output** the **nth BIU number**

## Test Cases

***Input->Output***

```
1->1  
2->21   
42->23595  
100->118300    
200->415777    
300->800175
```

This is [codegolf](/questions/tagged/codegolf).Shortest answer in bytes wins!

Comment: But `1` is not prime...

Comment: @Stephen thats why I said "For the case of 1 we take as distinct prime factor 1". This is my challenge and this is one of the rules of this challenge.I didn't say that 1 is prime.

Comment: Why are the numbers called "BIU"?

Comment: I'm not sure but I think that it has to do with bisexual intellectual unicorns using them in their everyday life (not in our universe of course...)

Comment: Downvoters, don't be shy. Share your thoughts with the rest of us.

Answer (score 6):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), <s>16</s> 15 bytes

```
ÆDÆfQ€SS‘ḍ
1Ç#Ṫ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ASYA2f9qZWxsef//w4ZEw4ZmUeKCrFNT4oCY4biNCjHDhyPhuar///8yMA)

Woohoo for builtins (but they mysteriously hide from me sometimes so *-1 byte thanks to @HyperNeutrino*)

**How it Works**

```
ÆDÆfQ€SS‘ḍ - define helper function: is input a BIU number?
ÆD             - divisors
  Æf           - list of prime factors
    Q€         - now distinct prime factors
      SS       - sum, then sum again ('' counts as 0)
        ‘      - add one (to account for '')
         ḍ     - does this divide the input?

1Ç#Ṫ - main link, input n
  #     - starting at 
1          - 1
        - get the first n integers which meet:
 Ç         - helper link
   Ṫ    - tail
```

Comment: -1 byte using `ÆfQ€` instead of `ÆFḢ€€`

Comment: `but they mysteriously hide from me sometime` "Jelly is a game of atom hide and programmer seek" ~ i cri everytim

Comment: I think you can save 1 byte with `ÆDÆFSSḢ‘ḍ`.

Answer (score 5):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 9 bytes

```
µNNÑfOO>Ö
```

Uses teh **05AB1E** encoding. [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/f//0FY/v8MT0/z97Q5P@//fFAA)

Answer (score 4):

## [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk), 13 bytes

```
!fṠ¦ö→ΣṁoupḊN
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ASIA3f9odXNr//8hZuG5oMKmw7bihpLOo@G5gW91cOG4ik7///81)

#### Explantaion

```
  Ṡ¦ö→ΣṁoupḊ    Predicate: returns 1 if BIU, else 0.
           Ḋ    List of divisors
       ṁ        Map and then concatenate
        oup     unique prime factors
      Σ         Sum
    ö→          Add one
  Ṡ¦            Is the argument divisible by this result
 f          N   Filter the natural numbers by that predicate
!               Index
```

Answer (score 3):

## Mathematica, 85 bytes

```
If[#<2,1,n=#0[#-1];While[Count[(d=Divisors)@++n,1+Tr@Cases[d/@d@n,_?PrimeQ,2]]<1];n]&
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Actually](https://github.com/Mego/Seriously), 16 bytes

```
u⌠;÷♂y♂iΣu@%Y⌡╓N
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0wuKU3Myan8/7/0Uc8C68PbH81sqgTizHOLSx1UIx/1LHw0dbLf//9GAA)

Explanation:

```
u⌠;÷♂y♂iΣu@%Y⌡╓N
u⌠;÷♂y♂iΣu@%Y⌡╓   first n+1 numbers x starting with x=0 where
   ÷                divisors
    ♂y              prime factors of divisors
      ♂iΣu          sum of prime factors of divisors, plus 1
  ;       @%        x mod sum
            Y       is 0
               N  last number in list
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Pyth](https://github.com/isaacg1/pyth), 22 bytes

```
e.f|qZ1!%Zhssm{Pd*M{yP
```

[Try it here!](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=e.f%7CqZ1%21%25Zhssm%7BPd%2aM%7ByP&input=54&test_suite=1&test_suite_input=1%0A2%0A3%0A4%0A5%0A6%0A7&debug=0)

This is my first ever Pyth solution, I began learning it thanks to the recommendations of some very kind users in chat :-)... Took me about an hour to solve.

### Explanation

```
e.f|qZ1!%Zhssm{Pd*M{yP  - Whole program. Q = input.

 .f                     - First Q integers with truthy results, using a variable Z.
     qZ1                - Is Z equal to 1?
   |                    - Logical OR.
                   {yP  - Prime factors, powerset, deduplicate.
                 *M     - Get the product of each. This chunck and ^ are for divisors.
              m}Pd      - Get the unique prime factors of each.
           ss           - Flatten and sum.
          h             - Increment (to handle that 1, bah)
       %Z               - Modulo the current integer by the sum above.
      !                 - Logical negation. 0 -> True, > 0 -> False.
e                       - Last element.
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), 115 bytes

All of the list comprehensions here can probably be golfed down, but I'm not sure how. Golfing suggestions welcome! [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PY3BCoMwEETv/YoNeFCqofGsf@Ctx7CHlVosdaMYpTHk31NDoYdhmDcwM5J9D9MUoxNHuw4MDo5GXXowraZATaWVlFiSyNXV7qyTfPAnr6VkLFn4ksxDm3nLvHDB/RpfKUQMfKY/ozTjEAsUIjeVKiLTy0ALy77dt7UzkIEd589pT6YFekjf9Q3jFw)

```hs
x!y=rem x y<1
b n=[a|a<-[1..],a!(1+sum[sum[z|z<-[2..m],m!z,and[not$z!x|x<-[2..z-1]]]|m<-[x|x<-[2..a],a!x]])]!!(n-1)
```

**Ungolfing**

This answer is actually three functions mashed together.

```hs
divisors a = [x | x <- [2..a], rem a x == 0]
sumPrimeDivs m = sum [z | z <- [2..m], rem m z == 0, and [rem z x /= 0 | x <- [2..z-1]]]
biu n = [a | a <- [1..], rem a (1 + sum [sumPrimeDivs m | m <- divisors a]) == 0] !! (n-1)
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), <s>22</s> <s>21</s> 17 [bytes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1)

<s>I feel like the `g` function method should lead to a shorter solution, but I can't figure out how it works!</s> Nope! Wrong method! But, in my defense, the `i` method didn't exist at the time.

1-indexed.

```
ÈvXâ mk câ x Ä}iU
```

[Try it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&code=yHZY4iBtayBj4iB4IMR9aVU&input=MjA)

```
ÈvXâ mk câ x Ä}iU     :Implicit input of integer U
È                     :Function taking an integer X as argument
 v                    :  Test X for divisibility by
  Xâ                  :    Divisors of X
     m                :    Map
      k               :      Prime factors
        c             :    Flatten after
         â            :      Deduplicating
           x          :    Reduce by addition
             Ä        :    Add 1
              }       :End function
               iU     :Get the Uth integer that returns true
```